# MapStruct @AfterMapping scope

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

With [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/AfterMapping.html) does `@AfterMapping` have to apply to every method on the class?

Should each EntityDTO have its own mapper class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not Each EntityDTO should have its own MapperClass. Each Entity should have its own class. Considering you have the Entity User. The your Mapper can look something like this:

```
@Mapper(config = MappingConfig.class)
public interface UserMapper {

  @Mapping(target = "someValue", ignore = true)
  UserDTO2 mapToEntity(User userEntity);

  UserDTO1 mapToEntity(User userEntity);

  @AfterMapping
  default void setAfterMappingAnlageToDto(User source, @MappingTarget UserDTO1 target) {
      // your logic for the first DTO
  }

  @AfterMapping
  default void setAfterMappingAnlageToDto(User source, @MappingTarget UserDTO2 target) {
      // your logic for the second DTO
  }

}
```

As you can see, it is possible to tell @AfterMapping to only be used with a specific DTOs.